# Calling MySQL from .NET works locally but not at ISP (HostGator)

Tags: mysql, .net

After I installed the "MySQL .NET Connector libraries", the following C# code works great on my local development machine:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

I can query my local database and it works!

When I upload this code to my hosting company (HostGator), I get a 404 error.  When I remove that single "using" line, the page loads fine.

Their tech support claims that the MySQL .NET Connector Libraries are installed on their shared windows machine.  Beyond that they tell me to "contact a developer".

Their site has no examples of linking .NET with MySQL, but even if it did I can't even get to the part about connection strings.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?
Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 0):

I have been unable to find out why

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

fails on the remote system, but I did find a work around.  If you have an account at HostGator and would like to work with MySQL using .NET, you can make it work via their ODBC connection.  A working connection string (on 2/22/18 anyway) is

```
connectionString="DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; PORT=3306;DATABASE=mydb; USER=myUID; PASSWORD=myPWD;"
```

This is not in their documentation anywhere.  This will allow you to issue the following library call

```
using System.Data.Odbc;
```

I'm posting this here because my guess is that someone else will have this issue and won't be able to find the answer with their tech support.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of HostGator customer support, I have finally found out how to accomplish this.  I had to add the following lines to web.config:

```
<add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
<add assembly="MySql.Web, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
```

I also had to add the following to the ASPX page

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MySql.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" %>
```

I hope this helps someone else.